# How do I read a .txt file from an input element in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, javascript-objects

I am making a code that can take one or more .obj files from an input element and use the text content of those files in the code. right now I'm only trying to log the text of the file just to try to get it working. This is what I currently have to load the files

HTML:

```
<input type="file", id="modelImport", name="modelImport", accept=".obj" multiple>
```

JavaScript:

```
function loadFiles(){
    const fileList = modelImport.files; //gets list of files from input element
    const reader = new FileReader; //creates the file reader
    for(let i=0; i<fileList.length; i++){ // iterate through each file
        var text = reader.readAsText(fileList[i]) // convert file to text, which is having trouble
        console.log(text)
    }
}
const modelImport = document.getElementById("modelImport");
modelImport.addEventListener("change", loadFiles);
```

As of right now, console.log gives me "undefined" when the code is run.
I'm not using any libraries right now, but I'm on the fence about adding one for this one function.

Comment: why are there commas in your HTML element markup?

Answer (score 0):

Because `undefined` is [the return value for `readAsText()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsText).  Using the example from that documentation, you want to listen to the `load` event on the `FileReader` object.  For example:

```js
function loadFiles() {
    const fileList = modelImport.files; //gets list of files from input element
    const reader = new FileReader(); //creates the file reader

    reader.addEventListener(
        "load",
        function() {
            // when the file has been read, display it
            console.log(reader.result)
        },
        false
    );

    for (let i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++) { // iterate through each file
        reader.readAsText(fileList[i]) // read the file
    }
}
const modelImport = document.getElementById("modelImport");
modelImport.addEventListener("change", loadFiles);
```

```html
<input type="file", id="modelImport", name="modelImport", accept=".obj" multiple>
```